# Prove that a nonempty subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is closed if and only if $d(x,C)>0 $ for each point $x$ in the complement of $C$

Tags: general-topology

> Prove that a nonempty subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is closed if and only if $d(x,C)\gt 0$ for each point $x$ in the complement of $C$.

I have the first direction of the proof. 
Now assume $d(x,C)\gt 0$ for each point $x$ in the complement of $C$ and that $C$ is nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Show $C$ is closed.

Since $d(x,C)\gt 0$ and $C=\mathbb{R}\setminus(\mathbb{R}\setminus C))$, we have $d(x,\mathbb{R}\setminus(\mathbb{R}\setminus C))\gt 0$. From here, do I have to show there is an open interval centered at $x$ and contained in $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$? Which then implies $\mathbb{R}\setminus C$ is open?

Comment: If $d(x,C)=\delta>0$, then for all $c\in C$, $d(x,c)\geq \delta$. So if $y\in\mathbb{R}$ is such that $d(x,y)<\delta$, then...

Comment: To show that $C$ is closed, show that the complement $\mathbb{R} \setminus C$ is open. Now for every $x$ in the complement of $C$ find an open ball around $x$.

Comment: @PaulK would the open ball be centered around an arbitrary a? with arbitrary radius r?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin then... y is not contained in C?

Comment: @Ashley: Correct. Which means...

Comment: @arturomagidin the complement is open?

Comment: Are you asking me or telling me?

Answer (score 1):

$C$ is closed

$\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathbb{R} \setminus C$ is open

$\Leftrightarrow$ $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus C, \exists \varepsilon > 0, (x-\varepsilon, x + \varepsilon) \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus C$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus C, \exists \varepsilon > 0, (x-\varepsilon, x + \varepsilon) \cap C = \emptyset$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus C, \exists \varepsilon > 0, d(x,C) > \varepsilon$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus C, d(x,C) > 0$

Comment: are those supposed to be backwards brackets?

Comment: Sorry, I used the French notation ! I edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence in $C$ which converges to $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We have
$$d(x, C) \le d(x, x_n) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

so $d(x, C) = 0$. If we had $x \notin C$, it would be $d(x,C) > 0$ which is a contradiction. Hence $x \in C$ so $C$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.